# Tensor Flow passing a tensor to optimizer minimize function trains better

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am encountering something a bit strange (to me) in tensorflow and was hoping someone could shed some light on the situation.

I have a simple neural network that processes images.  The cost function I am minimizing is the simple MSE.

At first I implemented the following:

```
cost = tf.square(DECONV - Y)
```

which I then passed to my optimizer as follows:

```
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

I was able to obtain great results with this implementation.  However, as I tried to implement a regularizer, I realized that I wasn't passing a scalar value to the optimizer.minimize() but in fact passing a tensor of shape [batch, dim_x, dim_y].

I changed my implementation to the following:

```
cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(Y, DECONV)
```

as well as many variations of this like:

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.subtract(DECONV, Y)))
```

etc.

My issue is that with these new implementations of the MSE I am not able to even come close to the results I obtained using the original "wrong" implementation.

Is the original way a valid way to train? If so, how can I implement regularizers? If not, what am I doing wrong with the new implementations? Why can't I replicate the results?

Answer (score 1):

Can you precise what you mean by

> I was able to achieve greater result [..]

I assume that you have another metric than `cost` - this time an actual scalar, which enables you to compare the models trained by each method.

Also, have you tried adjusting the learning rate for the second method? I ask this because my intuition is that when you ask tensorflow to minimize a tensor (which has no mathematical meaning as far as I know), it minimizes the scalar obtained by summing over all the axis of the tensor. This is how `tf.gradients` works, and the reason why I think this is happening. So maybe in the second method if you multiply the learning rate by `batch*dim_x*dim_y` you would get the same behavior as in the first method.

Even if this works, I don't think passing a tensor to the `minimize` function is a good idea - minimization of a d-dimensional value has no meaning as you have no order rule in such spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  By better results I mean the overall cost was about 2 orders of magnitude better (ie 0.00002 vs 0.002).  Also comparing the images shows the first method to replicate the labelled image much better.  The learning rate for the first method is about 0.0005...so multiplying this by a very large number doesn't seem to be right...?  I have tried adjusting the learning rate for the second method and found one that trains okay, but I can't get the cost down to 2e-5.

Comment: I don't know what the architecture of your network is but indeed it doesn't seem reasonable to use such a large learning rate.

Comment: Does the same phenomenon happens with other optimizers (adam, sgd, ..) ?

Comment: I confirmed and you are indeed correct about what the optimizer does.  If I implement `cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(DECONV - Y))` it gives me the same results as the first case.  For some reason, adding the mean to this (in this case dividing by the number of elements batch * dim_x * dim_y) completely impedes training.  Unfortunately I am restricted to using rmsprop.

Comment: Actually, what you want is not `tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(DECONV - Y))` but rather `tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(DECONV - Y), axis=[1,2]), axis=0)` therefore the mean L2-loss on your dataset). Then multiply your learning rate by batch_size to get the good behavior you noticed for the first method, with the formulation of the loss that makes sense.

Comment: Ifaury, this works, but what I want is the MSE of the images.  This other implementation isn't the MSE.  I am hoping to understand and be able to get the MSE to train as well as this other implementation, which I don't understand why it isn't.  Why would a scaling factor so dramatically effect the training?

Comment: I thought you wanted the mean l2 loss over all the images. The scaling factor indeed doesn't impact your loss landscape, except by rescaling the gradient (hence the need to rescale the learning rate). My intuition was that you had found a good learning rate for the first case, and that you could derive from it a good learning rate for the second method. If it is not the case, I don't really understand why minimizing the result of tf.reduce_mean() is fundamentally different from tf.reduce_sum()